# Change connector style

Tags: vba, visio

I want to highlight connectors of a Shape object, but it doesn't give me any LineStyle properties for the connector itself. Here's what I got so far:

```
    For i = 0 To UBound(lngShapeIDs)
      Dim shp As Shape

      Dim connect As connect
      Set shp = ActivePage.Shapes.ItemFromID(lngShapeIDs(i))
      shp.LineStyle = "Guide"
      shp.BringToFront
      Set connect = shp.FromConnects.Item(i + 1)
    Next
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what specific line style properties you would like to set? Knowing that would help direct the answer.

Comment: I would like to a) set the line color of the connector and b) bring it to the front. Same thing as with the Shape object, but for the connect. I actually would assume the connector being of a Shape type, as it's just a line - obviously it is not.

Answer (score 3):

Based in your comments this is what I think you are looking for

```
Dim shape As shape
For Each shape In ActivePage.Shapes
    If (shape.OneD <> 0) Then
        shape.CellsU("LineColor").Formula = "rgb(255,0,0)"
        shape.BringToFront
    End If
Next
```

This sample enumerates through all the shapes in the page. It assumes and "1-D" shapes are connectors that need to be modified. For those connectors, their line color is set to red and they are each brought to the front.

So if this was the initial state of the drawing:

[image]

Then after running the VBA code, the drawing will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this surely works - my problem is, that I don't have the connectors as Shapes, but as Connect objects. They don't have LineColor, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, documentation about these things is really, really rare and poorly structured

Comment: Starting with Visio 2016 you will get exceptions doing it this way. Instead use FormulaU.